# how to calculate the covariance of sample central moments

Tags: probability-or-statistics, symbolic

$\bar{x}= \sum_{i=1} ^{n}  \frac{1}{n}x_{i}$

$m_1=\sum _{i=1} ^{n}   \frac{1}{n} (x_{i}-\bar{x})$

$m_2=\sum _{i=1} ^{n}   \frac{1}{n} (x_{i}-\bar{x})^2 $

$m_3=\sum _{i=1} ^{n}   \frac{1}{n}(x_{i}-\bar{x})^3 $

how to get the explicit solution of the co-variance matrix of $\bar{x},m_1,m_2,m_3$,
thanks !

Simulation for code(R code)

n=10^5
simu.num=10^4
for(simu in 1:simu.num) {
    w1=rbeta(n,shape1=2,shape2=5)
    v1=w1-mean(w1)
    c1[simu]=mean(w1)
    c2[simu]=mean(v1^2)
    c3[simu]=mean(v1^3)}

W1=rbeta(10^6,shape1=2,shape2=5)

theta6=mean((W1-mean(W1))^6)
theta3=mean((W1-mean(W1))^3)
theta2=mean((W1-mean(W1))^2)
theta4=mean((W1-mean(W1))^4)
theta5=mean((W1-mean(W1))^5)
theta5=mean((W1-mean(W1))^6)

> cov(c2,c3)*n
>   [1] 0.0002295468
>
> theta5-4*theta2*theta3
>   [1] -3.909604e-06

Here \theta_{j} is the jth central moments

Comment: This site is for the computer algebra software *Mathematica*. This question does not relate to that, and would be more appropriate for [Statistics.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It sure does relate to Mma ... in fact, calculating it without mma would be a nightmare.

Comment: @wolfies have to agree with you there. It would be "interesting" to calculate those.

Comment: In Mathematica, the mean is just `Mean[list]` and the central moments are just `CentralMoment[list, r]`

Comment: @BobHanlon The user's input is not a data set, but rather a symbolic statistic such as the sample variance which is itself a random variable. `CentralMoment[list]` does something very different.

Comment: I don't think R code will go down very well here. Suggest convert that to _Mathematica_ code if you want some help with the simulation ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem known as finding moments of moments. In this case, we seek the covariance (*i.e.* the $\mu_{1,1}$ central moment) of various sample moments. The *modus operandi* for solving such problems is to work with power sum notation $s_r$, namely:

$$s_r = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^r$$

In this case, you are interested in the sample mean $ = \frac{s_1}{n}$, and the $2^{nd}$, $3^{rd}$ and $4^{th}$ sample central moments which can be expressed in terms of power sums using the functions:

[image]

where I am using the `SampleCentralToPowerSum` functions from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*. That completes the set-up.

**Solution**

The covariance operator is just the $\mu_{1,1}$ central moment ... so:

- $Cov(m_2,m_3)$ is given by:

[image]

where $\mu_r$ denotes the $r^{th}$ central moment of $X$ i.e. $\mu_r = E[(X-\mu)^r]$ and `CentralMomentToCentral` is another function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*.

- Similarly, $Cov(\bar{x}, m_4)$ is given by:

[image]

- $Cov(\bar{x}, m_3)$ is:

[image]

etc ... One can easily and immediately compute all the possible covariance relations in this manner. Doing so without a computer algebra system is extremely difficult. The solutions can be quite long (to visually present), so it is probably better to do them one by one, rather than try to display them all in one big variance-covariance matrix.

P.S. Just as a note, by definition $m_1 = 0$.

Comment: hi, great thanks!! I do a little simulation about the cov(m2,m3) part, the answer is not consistent with the formula given above, and what's the covariance of cov(s1/n, m3)?

Comment: I think you will need to show us your simulation to comment further on that component. I have added $Cov(\frac{s_1}{n}, m_3)$ to the above.

Comment: Grear thanks! @wolfies. I will definitely learn howto use this amazing Mathematica, since it cost me several weeks calculate these things, while did not get all the right answers. I do not know how to paste code in the comment, since it will show in the same row. I put it in my question above. By the way, I could not see the part cov(s1/n,m3) yet...

Comment: You may have to refresh the browser window to see the update ...

Comment: It's right, I found where I am wrong. Great thanks for your precious help.： ）

Comment: By the way, do you have any recommendation for tutorial book for mathmatica? Thank you